# Hit a Submittbutton in a Webpage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I using Winrt, I try to parse a HTML Page for Results.

But to get the result, I must fill out a search page and hit the submit button.

Is that possible to do that by code in Win RT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you haven't downloaded the page yet (or displayed in a WebView). To make a request have a closer look at [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx) and [HttpClientHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781241.aspx). Depending on whether the page uses GET or POST you will need to create a [HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.aspx) additionally. Search for the url of the form (most often the form's action attribute) to know your request uri.

Example:

```
var ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
ClientHandler.UseCookies = true;
ClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
ClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
ClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

var Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");           
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

var Response = await Client.GetAsync(RequestUri);
```

Your RequestUri could be something like http://www.example.com/search?query=search. But if the page you want uses POST to submit your query I think you need to create a HttpRequestMessage as below:

```
var RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
RequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(YourPostData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
RequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(OtherRequestUri);
Response = await Client.SendAsync(RequestMessage);
```

To parse the content of the response you best use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you find your button using WinJS query, you can programatically fire the click event like this:

```
element.fireEvent("onclick");
```

Comment: Hi thx for your response. But I didn't do this in the Xaml or html. I want to do that operations in the ViewModel or in some Helper classes. I hoped that there exists a WebClient Toolkit or s.th. but the winRt didn't have that i think.

Comment: I see what you mean, yeah I'm not 100% sure you can directly talk to the view side of things in this way, I'm sure something will come along at some point though.

Comment: I had a look and I think you can use the portable HttpClient package from here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek13PortableHttpClientMakesPortableLibrariesMoreUseful.aspx